# Python3 Sqlite3 - Checking if name refers to registered sqlite3 type

Tags: python-3.x, types, sqlite

Given a string `queried_type`, how do I check to see whether `queried_type` is a valid type in `sqlite3` for python 3?

That is, `queried_type` might be `'integer'` or `'text'`, but it might also be `'foo'` or `'bobby\'); drop table students; --'`.  I need to determine if `queried_type` refers to a valid sqlite3 type without exposing myself to sql injection attacks, and still allowing the programmer to use `register_adapter` and `register_converter`.

Comment: There's only 5 options... https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: In basic sqlite, yes.  However, the python sqlite3 module allows the programmer to register additional types with `register_adapter` and `register_converter`.  See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite-and-python-types)